# Java Logger in subclass

Tags: java, logging

To get C.run() to use its own class logger, should I add a public/protected method getLogger() in B?

```
public abstract class A extends Thread {
    @Override
    public abstract void run();
}

public class B extends A {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(B.class.getName());

    @Override
    protected void run() {
        // do something

        logger.info("B");
    }
}

public class C extends B {
}
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting? Have you tried?

Comment: Why do you need subclasses to use it's own loggers?

Comment: Each of the subclasses of A will be executed by a task engine. Some classes (like C in my example) extends another task. If C does not override B.run() I have no way to force it to use its own logger. Unless I add a getLogger() method.

Comment: But if C doesn't override B.run() then what is C doing?  Presumably it has methods which are called, which you can log to its own logger.  If you really want to (and are sure it's a good idea) to always log to the B,C Logger instance depending on which is the concrete implementation you could have the Logger getLogger() method which polymorphically returns the lowest Logger in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 14):

Well the Loggers are ideally set at Class level.  So if C needs it own Logger then declare its own Logger in C e.g.

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(C.class.getName());
```

This way when C runs some code it logs to its own Logger and when B runs it logs to its own Logger.  You'll be able to clearly see which Class logs what this way.

If this isn't what you're after please expand the question with what you're trying to achieve and why.

I'm not convinced if the following code is a good idea (I always want the Class which is physically running the code to be the Logger) but it should work:

```
public abstract class A extends Thread {
    @Override
    public abstract void run();
    protected abstract Logger getLogger();
}

public class B extends A {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(B.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void run() {
        getLogger().info("B");
    }

    @Override
    protected Logger getLogger() {return logger;);  
}

public class C extends B {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(C.class.getName());

    @Override
    protected Logger getLogger() {return logger;);  
}
```

Comment: Your modification of my example was exactly how I saw a possible solution.

Comment: Yep if that's what you're after - that's about the only way I can see it happening (reinstated now - I'd missed the curly braces... DOH!)

Comment: If you're OK with the logger not being static, the other Answer by @StKiller achieves the same benefits as this Answer, but in vastly more concise code.

Answer (score 5):

You may use this in base class:

```
protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
```

`this.getClass()` will initialize the logger with subclass name.

Comment: I guess this issue with making it non-static is that each instance of the Object will make this call.  I know it will return the existing logger, but it's still extra code executing in the java.util.Logger class to look it up for each new instance.

Comment: Yep, but I don't see any solution without drawbacks here. Anyway, if each new subclass requires to define a new logger in specified style - there is a problem with design, imho.

Comment: Well I guess it depends what your design objective is - if you're happy with a Class hierarchy logging to the same logger then just declare it at the top of the tree and allow all subclasses to log to it.  If you want to log for each class then give each subclass its own Logger.  I've always gone for the each subclass has its own logger approach.

Comment: I would delete the "If you will use non-abstract base class" as you *can* use that in an abstract base class. Also the use of `this` is unnecessary as you can just use `getClass()`.

Comment: @Jason S - I don't use "this" to specify the subclass. It's used just for more readable code. Thank you for suggestion about "non-abstract".

Comment: In reference to comment by @PlanetJones:  If your class hierarchy has all abstract classes except for the bottom-most/leaf concrete classes, then declaring at the top of the class hierarchy tree/root in the manner of this Answer indeed does give each concrete its own logger.

Comment: Following up on comment by @Jason_S to make the code in this Answer more concise...  '.getName()' can also be removed:    Constructing with just the Class<?> will return an identical logger; that constructor itself calls getName() within it anyways.

Comment: This doesn't work. When you call logger.info("whatever") the formatter will print the class name where "logger" was declared, not the one returned from "this.getClass().getName()", even when "logger.getName()" returns the correct value.